# How to prevent 'ALL' from being selected as an option in dropdown in a flex dashboard when a user has capability to select multiple options?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

In the application, the user has the capability to select one or multiple different manufacturers in the dropdown menu. They are also able to select ALL as an option as well. Although, when someone selects 'ALL' as an option, they are also able to select other manufacturers as well. Functionally, I want the user to select 'ALL' then  when they select other manufacturers, I want 'ALL' to not be selected and to be removed as input in the textbox.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is the data:

Here is the code:

````
---
title: "Test"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: rows
  vertical_layout: fill

runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(tidyquant)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(pins)
library(shiny)
library(httr)
library(XML)
library(DT)
library(plotly)
library(purrr)




 test_data  <- structure(list(Toys = c("Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", "Slinky", 
"Slinky", "Slinky", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", 
"Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Tin Solider", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo", 
"Hungry Hungry Hippo", "Hungry Hungry Hippo"), Manufacturer = c("Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer A", 
"Manufacturer A", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", 
"Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer B", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", "Manufacturer C", 
"Manufacturer C"), Price = c(5.99, 6.99, 7.99, 9, 6, 5.54, 7, 
9.99, 6.99, 6.75, 8, 7.99, 9.99, 7.99, 5.99, 8.99, 10.99, 9.75
), change = c(0, 16.69449082, 14.30615165, 12.640801, -33.33333333, 
-7.666666667, 0, 42.71428571, -30.03003003, -3.433476395, 18.51851852, 
-0.125, 0, -20.02002002, -25.03128911, 50.08347245, 22.24694105, 
-11.28298453), Dates = c("1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", 
"7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", "3/1/2021", 
"5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021", "1/1/2021", 
"3/1/2021", "5/1/2021", "7/1/2021", "9/1/2021", "10/1/2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))
names(test_data) <- c("Toys", "Manufacturer", "Price", "change", "Dates")

```


Sidebar {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}

selectInput("Toys",
            label = "Toys",
            choices = unique(sort(test_data$Toys)),
            selected = "Slinky")


selectizeInput("Manufacturer",
            label = "Manufacturer",
            choices = as.character(unlist(test_data %>%
             dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
             dplyr::arrange(Manufacturer) %>%
               distinct())), 
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(placeholder = 'Make a selection below'))               
```

Column 
-------------------------------------
```{r}
#Hides initial error messages
tags$style(type="text/css",
  ".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",
  ".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"
)


observe({
if (!is.null(input$Toys)){
  updateSelectInput(
    inputId = "Manufacturer",
    choices = test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys) %>%
      dplyr::select(Manufacturer) %>%
      dplyr::distinct() %>%
      dplyr::pull(Manufacturer) %>%
      str_sort %>%
      append('ALL', after = 0), 
    selected = c('ALL')
    )
  }
})



Toys_reactive <- reactive({
  if(input$Manufacturer == "ALL"){
    Toys_reactive <- test_data %>%
      dplyr::filter(Toys == input$Toys)
  }
  else if(length(unique(test_data$Manufacturer)) >= 1){
    Toys_reactive = NULL
    for(i in input$Manufacturer){
      subset_toys <- test_data %>% 
        dplyr::filter(Manufacturer == i & Toys == input$Toys)
      Toys_reactive <- rbind(Toys_reactive, subset_toys)
    }
  }
  Toys_reactive
})
````

Here's an example of what is happening:

[image]

I would like ALL to not be included in the textbox when the user selects a specific manufacturer or multiple different manufacturers.

Comment: Sorry, I want the user to be able to select a single/multiple manufacturers  or select 'ALL'. I don't want the user to be able to select 'ALL' as well as Manufacturer A, Manufacturer B, and Manufacturer C. Thus, once Manufacturer A is selected, then 'ALL' should not be included as an input in the textbox.

Comment: Oh, 'ALL' should always appear as an option in the dropdown but once it is selected then Manufacturer A, B, and C should disappear in the textbox.